# Can get the Unique column values but need help trimming the resulting string/range

Tags: vba, excel

I am using this code to get the unique value from a column and return that value to a cell on a  separate workbook.  So far so good, as this works as is.

However, I am looking to expand upon it by trimming the results from '36 Months' down to just the integers value '36'.  I haven't been able to find any related articles that address this specifically.

Code:

```
Dim Sh1, Sh2 As Worksheet
Dim Rng2 As Range

Set Sh1 = wbFrom.Worksheets("Sheet0")
Set Rng2 = Sh1.Range("X9:X" & Sh1.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row)
Set Sh2 = wbTo.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Rng2.Cells(1, 1).Copy Sh2.Cells(1, 1)
Rng2.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Sh2.Range("F12"), Unique:=True
```

Data:

```
Duration (Months)
36 Months
37 Months
<Blank row>
<Blank row>
36 Months
```

I can't seem to do anything like 'Msgbox Rng2' or 'Msgbox Rng2.value' to get the string to begin playing with it.  How can I get a 'range' into a values, and update those values how I want to?

EDIT:

So I changed

```
CopyToRange:=Sh2.Range("F12") to 
CopyToRange:=Sh2.Left(Range("F12").Value2, 2)
```

and it says it does not recognize 'left' as a command. 
I also tried to adapt this line, but the same issue:

```
Set Rng2 = Sh1.Range("X9:X" & 
Sh1.Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row)
```

(This is a single line but is wrapped here)

I have also tried the VAL() example, here:

```
Rng2.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Val(Sh2.Range("F12")), Unique:=True which is also apparently incorrect syntax. As well as Val(Rng2.Cells(1, 1)).Copy Sh2.Cells(1, 1)
```

--> How would I implement this in my existing code or is this some additional step I have to add that I am missing?

Comment: Note that if you `Dim Sh1, Sh2 As Worksheet` that `Sh1` is of type `Variant`! You need to specify a type for **every** variable: `Dim Sh1 As Worksheet, Sh2 As Worksheet`. • `Val("36 Months")` will return `36`. • You will need to read your data into an array first (`Dim MyArray As Variant: MyArray = Range("A1:A5").Value)`) and then loop through that array to do your replacement.

Comment: Thanks PEH - I am going to have to look up how to impliment either of these as they are both new to me.  How do you utilize the 'Val()' to return the 36 -- or is that what you meant has to be in the array?

Comment: to get the first two characters in a string take a look at the `Left()` function To get the first two chars in range("A1"), do: `Left(Range("A1").Value2, 2)`. Note that this will only work on one value at a time.

Comment: I have also tried the VAL() example, here:     Rng2.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Val(Sh2.Range("F12")), Unique:=True
  which is also apparently incorrect syntax.   As well as Val(Rng2.Cells(1, 1)).Copy Sh2.Cells(1, 1)

Comment: @EricKing Please always add the code into the original question (you can [edit] it). Code is pretty much not readable in comments due to lacking formatting (which is absolutely necessary as a single line break can change the code completely).